# RecyclerView separate the swipe left event from sub value Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-swipe

I am developing an Android app. I am using RecyclerView to display a list.

Here is my list item one card:

[image]

I have implemented the left swipe on the card and showing two more options as shown below image.

[image]

Now the challenge I am facing is I want to implement left swipe on a header(i.e Maths(ICSC)) and wanted to show two different options for a header(i.e Maths(ICSC)) as shown in below image.

[image]

I tried ItemTouchHelper but it is diable the swipe effect of the card.

How should I achieve this? Am I missing something?